# MOSFET usage: single P-channel or H-bridge?

Tags: transistors, mosfet

I'm creating a power distribution board with different types of voltage regulation and management hardware. It needs to be able to switch 12 VDC on and off to other systems. I'm trying to figure out what type of power switching components I should use.

The MOSFETs will be switched by a 3.3 V microcontroller. The different systems will need to communicate together so they need to share a common ground, at least once powered up. My question is, should I use a P-channel MOSFET with transistor driver circuitry and have the grounds permanently connected, or should I use a H-bridge to connect both the 12 V and GND at the same time? I would prefer to not use N-channel MOSFETS as I don't want to risk destroying anything somehow if there is accidentally a way that the GNDs are already connected.

The MOSFETs will have to hold a max of 5 A (10 A comfortable margin) at 12 V.

What type of setup would be recommended for a situation like this? Is it better to just switch the 12 V with a P-channel or make a full H-bridge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are switching a dumb device such as a solenoid, a low-side switch is simpler.

If you switching electronic subsystems, you usually want to switch the high side.

You almost never need to switch both sides.

Here is a basic high-side switch. You could possibly omit R2 if Q1 is close to the MCU.

The resistor values should work for most setups, but you should consider the load characteristics and transistor types.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foYL5V.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly the answer I needed

Comment: If the load somehow exhibits a voltage greater than 12V, it could forward bias the body diode and feed into the supply.

Comment: Could you add an illustrative Q2 part number?